# Can CentOS deny SSH access to everyone but my IP?

Tags: ssh, centos

I was wondering how I could deny all SSH logins from any IP but mine? This would be using IPTables.

Comment: @Paul I honeslty didnt know where to start... I am not too fond of IPTables

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this using iptables - From the command line:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s MY.IP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

You can do a similar thing leaving out the /sbin/iptables, adding it near the top of /etc/sysconfig/iptables and then doing a restart.

If you want to steer clear of IPTables altogether you can simply modify the SSHD config by adding the following line to the end of /etc/ssh/ssd_config (and then restarting sshd)

```
AllowUsers  myuser@my.ip.address
```

(If there is more then one user you can use the form AllowUsers myuser@my.ip myuser2@myip myuser3@my.ip )

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to configure iptables as @davidgo has mentioned. Adding:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

to your /sbin/iptables might work (change the ip to the desired address).